# Makeindex no .nls file

Tags: indexing

Here is the sample code from test.tex: http://texblog.org/2012/05/14/list-of-symbols-or-abbreviations-nomenclature/

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Time Zones}
\begin{document}
UTC\nomenclature{UTC}{Coordinated Universal Time} is 3 hours behind ADT\nomenclature{ADT}{Atlantic Daylight Time} and 10 hours ahead of EST\nomenclature{EST}{Eastern Standard Time}.
\printnomenclature
\small\hfill Created by http://texblog.org
\end{document}
```

I ran this on TexStudio. 
pdfLatex --> MakeIndex --> pdfLatex

**Errors when I ran MakeIndex:**

Process started: makeindex.exe "test".idx

Input index file test.idx not found. Usage: makeindex.exe [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]

Process exited with error(s)

**Errors when I ran pdfLatex**

No file test.nls.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Read Section 2 of the »[nomencl](http://texdoc.net/pkg/nomencl)« manual.

Comment: And the sample source also points out in detail what to do to get the nomenclature.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

<sub>If every one reads manuals, then we will have very less questions here and less reputation too ;)</sub>

To make nomenclature you have to `pdflatex` the `.tex` file and then run this command:

```
makeindex -s nomencl.ist -t "<file name>.nlg" -o "<file name>.nls" "<file name>.nlo"
```

where `<file name>` is the name without `.tex` extension (`myfile` if I have `myfile.tex`).

Then again `pdflatex` `myfile.tex`.

Now the question is how to run `makeindex` with all those arguments in texstudio.

You can create a `user` command for this. Go to `Options` → `Configure TeXstudio`. In the window that appears, choose `Build` tab on the left side. Search for `User Commands`. (You may have to click `Add` button with a green `+`). Type

```
Make Nomenclature
```

just after `user0:` (0,or 1 0r 2, depending on how many use commands you already have) in the first box. In the second box type:

```
makeindex -s nomencl.ist -t %.nlg -o %.nls %.nlo
```

Now OK it.  Illustration below.

[image]

Now you have a menu under `Tools` → `User` with a short key also.

[image]

Now run `pdflatex` → `Make Nomeclature` → `pdflatex`. Hope things are now clear.

As another option, you can install the cool automation tool `arara` and create a `User Command` for arara (as mentioned above) and make all three compilation clicks in one go. You have to add these lines:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex
```

just before your `\documentclass` command (or anywhere in the document), and compile using

```
arara myfile
```

using your `User Command`.

Comment: With arara it's even easier.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I am writing it now :).

Comment: Thank you for your help Harish! Works perfectly! Have a great day :)

Comment: This can be done through a one click in Texniccenter by modifying the pdflatex to avoid using arara or the two steps compilation. Does the new version of Texstudio provide this?

Comment: Thank you for the solution Mr. Harish Kumar. But I tried it, it did not work for me. I tried both options. Please help me. I posted a new post at this form
[My New Post here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237894/error-input-index-file-full-idx-not-found-usage-makeindex-i-am-using-tex) about my problem and mentioned that I couldn't solve my problem using solution in this post. Thank you in advance...

Comment: The nomenclature manual says to write `makeindex <filename>.glo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.gls`, while for me that does not work. I have to write `makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.els`. Why?

Comment: @Marco `.els`? No idea! Are you trying use glossaries? We were talking about nomenclature. But using `arara` should work here too.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I use `makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls`. Here what the documentation says: "The previous versions of nomencl also used
the file extensions .glo and .gls for the generated output and input files.
These extensions have now been changed to .nlo and .nls respectively - again, for increased compatibility."

Comment: Result of my try: Input index file Report.nlo not found. Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcg] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]