# Nomenclature or Glossary not printed

Tags: nomenclature

I have this code, but the nomenclature is not printed, why? Im working on Mac with TeXStudio. Thank you in advance.

```
 % arara: nomencl
 % arara: pdflatex
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
 \usepackage[prefix]{nomencl}
 \newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}
 \makenomenclature

 \begin{document}
 This is a minimal working example.

 \printnomenclature

 And this is the equation that changed the world's history:
 \begin{equation} \label{relat}
    E=mc^2
 \end{equation}

 \nomenclature{$E$}{Energy\nomunit{J}}
 \nomenclature{$m$}{Mass\nomunit{kg}}
 \nomenclature{$c$}{Speed of light\nomunit{m/s}}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Have you run `makeindex` -- or does `arara` provide a rule for `nomencl` at all? If I run it by hand I've got a nomenclature

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `arara` does have a `nomencl` rule but it needs another `% arara: pdflatex` (before the `nomencl` rule).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Right, I just checked it -- Thanks for this information. I've never used `arara` before (don't tell Paulo ;-))

Comment: @ChristianHupfer lol, I'll keep it a secret ;-) It looks as though the `nomencl` rule doesn't set `-s` by default, so it would need to be `% arara: nomencl: {style: 'nomencl.ist'}` (I think that could do with fixing in the rule.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: You should answer -- you found the error

Comment: @ChristianHupfer okay, done :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `arara` directives at the start of the document need modifying slightly. First, you need `pdflatex` before `nomencl` (in addition to the one afterwards). Second, the `nomencl` rule doesn't seem to set the `makeindex` style file (through the `-s` switch). This ought to be fixed (paging Paulo, Marco, Brent, and, erm cough, me), but you can set it explicitly like this:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl: {style: 'nomencl.ist'}
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[prefix]{nomencl}
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
This is a minimal working example.

\printnomenclature

And this is the equation that changed the world's history:
\begin{equation} \label{relat}
   E=mc^2
\end{equation}

\nomenclature{$E$}{Energy\nomunit{J}}
\nomenclature{$m$}{Mass\nomunit{kg}}
\nomenclature{$c$}{Speed of light\nomunit{m/s}}
\end{document}
```

You may actually need another `pdflatex` to get the cross-references up-to-date:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl: {style: 'nomencl.ist'}
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
```

Comment: Sorry, but is not working. I have no idea waht the Arara is

Comment: @NicolásSacco I assumed that you had the lines `% arara:` in your document because you were using `arara`. (Why did you include them?) If you're just building your document by clicking on a "pdflatex" button or menu it (sorry I don't use TeXstudio so I don't know the interface), then you additionally need to run `makeindex` and then `pdflatex` again.

Comment: @NicolásSacco Perhaps [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161381) can help.